# Error loading image from Firebase to my Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to load my images from Firebase to my Table View but I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL'

When I print the object on its own it is definitely a URL.

This is what my code looks like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedItem", for: indexPath) as! FeedItem

    //TODO: Guard...

    let postImage = postArray [indexPath.row]
    let postImageURL = postImage.postImageURL
    let data = Data(contentsOf: postImageURL) // Line with Error

    cell.postImage.image = UIImage (data: data)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: FYI - Unless these are local URLs (files in your app's sandbox), do not use this code to load remote data. Use `URLSession`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the image in your cell, you need to convert the URL string into an actual URL object, which you can do via:

```
let postImage = postArray[indexPath.row]
if let postImageURL = URL(string: postImage.postImageURL)
{
    do {
         let data = try Data(contentsOf: postImageURL)
         cell.postImage.image = UIImage (data: data)
    } catch {
         print("error with fetching from \(postImageURL.absoluteString) - \(error)")
    }
}
```

And as rmaddy implies, your performance is not going to be very good (because depending on how far away the remote server is or how slow the internet is), the synchronous "`Data(contentsOf:`" call might take an unacceptably long time to succeed.  I'm just providing this answer so you will be able to see *something* in your own testing, but I wouldn't use this in production code.

Try to replace the `Data` fetch with an asynchronous `URLSession` task, and you can find much more information [in this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716279/downloading-images-in-uitableviewcell-data-vs-urlsession).

Comment: Thanks that worked and yes it was VERY slow so I used URLSession. This answer was still useful to me because I used it to create a URL Object from a URL with the Data syntax, which now makes sense to me for the first time :)